# Configuring Neomutt/Mutt to work with Gmail Labels

Tags: mutt

I just started using neomutt and was wondering is there a way to access Gmail labels using neomutt?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still wondering how to do this I think I have figured it out. So, you'll want to set up [mailboxes](https://neomutt.org/guide/configuration). 
An example would be:

```
mailboxes =label_name
mailboxes "maps://imap.gmail.com:993/label_name"
```

Comment: Do not forget to select "show in IMAP" in from of Labels you want from Gmail settings > Labels screen too!